# Не отображается фон после использования PainterEvent

Tags: python, pyqt5, qpushbutton, qpainter, paintevent

Столкнулся с затруднением: при применении `paintEvent` на `QPushButton` изображение не отображается, так же текст с кнопки пропал. Как это исправить?

Поиск меня ни к чему не привел, единственное что  я нашел - для кнопки необходимо задать стиль отображения для всех состояний. Так ли это?

**ps**. пользуясь случаем хотел бы ещё уточнить - возможно ли рисование нескольких изображений на одном виджете?(Я прочитал что не рекомендуется иметь 2 активных рисовальщика)

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from painter import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):   
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        centralwidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralwidget)
        main_box = QGridLayout(centralwidget)
    
        consumption_btn = PushButton_tb('Consumption \n calculator')
        main_box.addWidget(consumption_btn)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_()
```

**painter.py**

```
class PushButton_tb(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QPushButton.__init__(self)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        # painter.drawPixmap(0,0,QPixmap("resources/images/assets/btn_bg/btn_chat_transparent_normal_0.png"))
        bruh = QBrush(QPixmap("resources/images/assets/btn_bg/btn_chat_transparent_normal_0.png"))
        painter.setBackground(bruh)
        painter.setBackgroundMode(Qt.OpaqueMode)
        QPushButton.paintEvent(self, event)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

#from my_button import PushButtonTb
class PushButtonTb(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PushButtonTb, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        self.setFixedSize(300, 100)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        QPushButton.paintEvent(self, event)                               # !!! +++
    
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        
        # установите свое изображение     vvvvvv        
        painter.drawPixmap(5, 0, QPixmap("Ok.png").scaled(100, 100))      # !!! +++

        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.red, 5, Qt.SolidLine))
        painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(31, 176, 224)))
        painter.drawEllipse(QtCore.QRectF(225, 25, 50, 50))

#        QPushButton.paintEvent(self, event)
        

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):   
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()

        centralwidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralwidget)
        
        self.consumption_btn = PushButtonTb('Consumption \n calculator')
        
        main_box = QGridLayout(centralwidget)
        main_box.addWidget(
            self.consumption_btn,
            0, 0,            
            alignment=Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignBottom)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.resize(400, 500)
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Ok.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это работает, но проблема с отсутствием текста осталась, я так понимаю потому что рисунок прорисовывается после создания виджета поверх него. могу ли я это решить прописав текст внутри paintEvent?

Comment: @Rett_oo можете.  Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour